# Perform .NET Action on Database Change

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

We have a process that needs to fire when a change occurs to a specific database table in Oracle. At the moment a similar process has been developed using triggers and a bunch of subsequent database actions that occur when that trigger is fired.

However, in this solution we want to call a .NET component (most likely a service) when the change occurs to a row or bunch of rows in a database table. Now, you could implement a polling mechanism that will check the table at regular intervals for those modifications and then instantiate the service when it finds any. However, I would prefer a more event driven approach.

I assume this is something that has been done elsewhere so I was wondering what approaches other people have used for dealing with such requirements?

Thanks in advance

***Edit**: The process that fires when a change occurs to the underlying data is essentially a call to an external web service using some of the related data. I am beginning to think whether this call should occur as part of the same process that is submitting the data into the database, rather than being triggered by the data change itself.*

Comment: you don't really want a simple db level insert/update to cause calls to external (higher level) components/services do you?  Sounds like a nightmare to maintain and keep performant.  Also, what do you do after the service is called? (do more db operations?)

Comment: Essentially a process is kicked off when an item in a table is added or amended. This process works with external web services.

Comment: The flow just seems wrong (I assume: app->middleware->db->middleware->db ?) Again, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with the service calls, I guess I'm asking the "why" instead of trying to answer the "how".  Maybe the work done in service can be done before db DML?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in another comment further down I am beginning to think the best approach would be for the work to be done in the service that the initial app is calling (if the service existed but that is beside the point for now). So this service would make the change in the db and then as part of the workflow it would also call the subsequent process(es). I still need to see how achievable this is as there could be some constraints due to other apps. In which case to remove any coupling I may just utilise a polling mechanism. Not event based but easier to change dbs.

Comment: anyway you can clarify what the service is doing as edit in your OP?

Comment: Amended the original post a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Oracle Database Extensions for .NET](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28376/intro.htm).

From the linked article:

> Oracle Database Extensions for .NET provides the following:
>
> - A Common Language Runtime (CLR) host for Oracle Database
> - Data access through Oracle Data Provider for .NET classes
> - Oracle Deployment Wizard for Visual Studio .NET

You would still use triggers to detect the db changes but instead of firing all the db-side logic you describe you would now be able to execute that logic from a .NET module.

Comment: So essentially call the .NET component from a trigger directly? From an implementation perspective this sounds an approach, but putting my design hat on it doesn't feel right? I am not entirely sure if I can explain why either :)

Comment: Your requirement states: `in this solution we want to call a .NET component (most likely a service) when the change occurs`... The 'even driven' way to detect changes in a db is via triggers and you want to call a .NET component so I'm not sure why the misgivings. Btw, if you're worried, take a look at what SQL Server has done to enable the CLR since SQL 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, that requirement holds, I am just not sure whether this approach feels right. I know about the CLR in SQL Server and have never felt comfortable about that coupling either. I am thinking that perhaps an alternative approach would be to deal with the event that is causing the underlying change. So, when the change is going into the database, perform the subsequent action at the same time i.e. a .net component makes the db change and the "trigger" change as one action. Still thinking, thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle's .NET driver, you can use [Oracle Continuous Query Notification (CQN)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm) to do that.

You just give it a normal SELECT query, and it will fire a callback in your app whenever the resultset for that query changes.

The one caveot I know of is that when it initially runs the query to subscribe for continuous notification, it momentarily requires an exclusive lock. Usually its not a big deal since you just evecute it once at startup, so any other DB queries on the same table will be blocked for a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds possible but will likely take some leg work.  I think you want to look into the Oracle Access Manager
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12530_01/oam.1014/e10355/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Paul's; but does not assume that you have Oracle installed on a Windows machine.

You may use [dbms_scheduler](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) to create a job that will call your external process.

You may directly call an [remote external job from Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/SchedulerEnhancements_11gR1.php#remote_external_jobs) (this requires Oracle Scheduler Agent to be installed but nothing else)

it requires a bit of leg work to get the authentication set up and such, but this works.

then you utilize an [event to start your job](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/scheduse005.htm#CHDIAJEB)(called from your trigger).

This way, you may actually be able to utilize a lot of what you already have coded and just have the oracle scheduler to handle the rest.

Comment: So to summarise, a trigger will call an Oracle job which will call an external component?

Comment: @JonArchway, yes; more specifically the trigger will enqueue a message that will fire off the job.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides two mechanisms to deal with what describe in a rather nice way... on the DB side you implement triggers for detecting the changes or whatever should result in an action on the .NET side...

For the communication you use a publish/subsribe mechanism based on the Oracle built-in queueing technology (called Advanced Queueing Technology, AQ) - for a nice example see http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/AQ.html (not affiliated, just a happy customer).

Another option is to use built-in `DBMS_ALERTER` package for communication which is transactional and asynchronous - see for an example http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleAlerter.html

Just to be clear:
the above technologies (DBMS_ALERTER and AQ) are Oracle built-in ones, not specific to any 3rd-party libraries... you just need an ADO.NET provider supporting them...

**EDIT - after the EDIT from the OP:**

If you have control over the code or the call to the code that triggers the data change (WebService?) then it is indeed the best way to deal with it is purely on the .NET side of things... this also helps to deal with situations where such a change runs into an error etc.